# What are the north and south poles in current carrying straight wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Do current carrying straight wire have magnetic poles if so where are they located?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magcur.html

Answer (score 1):

No. A current carrying wire do not have poles. Actually all magnetic feilds are produced by currents and not magnetic poles. Even in parmanent magnets(which have poles) there is a surface current which give rise to their magnetic feilds.magnetic poles are just a concept to make the study of magnetism in matter easy.and hence it is not possible to assign north and south poles to every magnetic feild source

Answer (score 0):

In a current-carrying wire, the magnetic field lines form closed, concentric  circles that wrap around the wire. If you grasp the wire with your right hand so that your thumb is pointing in the direction of current flow, your fingers point in the direction of the magnetic field.